# Random numbers in C++ vs Java

Tags: java, c++, random

I have been using this in Java and I know what it produces:

```
Random r = new Random(); 
double mynum = r.nextDouble();
```

Whereas, I found this code in C++ which I wanted to use in Java:

```
srand(time(NULL));
double mynum = (double)rand() / RAND_MAX;
```

Are these both equal?

If no, then what would be the equivalent java code?

where equivalent means produce a similar sequence of numbers? And my scientific computation will not be affected by this conversion of code from C++ to Java.

I was assuming both as the same thing, not sure...

Comment: What does equivalent mean? Produces the same sequence of numbers? Produces the same range of numbers? That method of producing random numbers in C++ is deprecated, in favor of the new [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) library

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for mentioning the library. I have found this code somewhere and I am rewriting in Java.

Comment: That depends on whether or not `srand` uses the exact same [linear congruential generator](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) implementation `java.util.Random` uses.

Comment: `r.setSeed(System.nanoTime());` The `setSeed()` method takes a `long` as it's argument (the seed value), in this case the systems current time-stamp in nanoseconds. Is that what you were looking for?